# Unit testing in laravel using filesystems

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, filesystems

I'm doing unit testing using the filesystems config. I want to map my file system disk to a testing directory where I will put my files(JSON, Excel, txt) to be used by the application for testing purposes. I don't want to use fake directories as I need to put the file in the 'import' location.

filesystems.php:

```
'disks' => [
    'import' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '/import/clientname',
        'visibility' => 'private'
    ],
];
```

In the application, here is the function which i want to test:

```
public function importFile(){
    $filesystem = Storage::disk('import');
    
    ...
}
```

The solution I was thinking is to use this location for my testing:

[image]

Is there a way to implement this solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, for example, upload file with each of your disks, then assert if file exist in that directory.

Example of unit test for upload image with form:

```
public function testStorage()
{
    $file = UploadedFile::fake()->image('File10.png');
    $response = $this->post(route("save.image"), [
        'file' => $file,
    ]);
    $response
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertSessionHasNoErrors();
    Storage::disk('local')->assertExists("/images/" . $file->name);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Is there any setting to be done for it to take that path?

Comment: @user3910487 i edited my answer, hope helps

Comment: The main thing is to remember to use `fake()` when using `UploadedFile`.